# Why does chrono::system_clock returns microseconds whereas clock_gettime returns nanoseconds

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, nanotime

std::chrono::system_clock::time_since_epoch().count() gives me a result in microseconds.

I want the current time in nanoseconds. But I can't use high_resolution_clock because on my system it is an alias on steady_clock (the monotonic clock).

I know my system is nanoseconds capable, because if I use clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) I am getting a correct nanosecond-resolution epoch time.

How can I tell std::chrono to use the nanosecond resolution? I'd like to avoid using clock_gettime and stick to the cpp wrapper.

Comment: Please show your code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Which standard library? Which os? Which versions of both?

Comment: Problem was the standard library I was using (libc++). It uses microseconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am getting a correct nanosecond-resolution epoch time.

Are you? `clock_gettime` is *required* to return a time in nanoseconds, regardless of what clock you're accessing. This doesn't mean that `CLOCK_REALTIME` actually provides this resolution. It may internally only have microsecond resolution and expresses nanoseconds by multiplying by 1000.

By contrast, the *actual* resolution of a chrono clock is specified by the implementation. It is not a mandated part of the UI; it can vary from system to system *and* from clock to clock. So if a particular implementation's `system_clock::period` is in microseconds, then that is all the resolution the implementation is willing to claim to provide.

Maybe the implementation could provide more resolution, but if it could, it would probably say so. So if it doesn't, then that means the implementation doesn't feel comfortable claiming to provide more resolution.

However, if you feel that `clock_gettime` really does provide better resolution (rather than simply giving more digits), you can just use that. In C++20, `system_clock` is explicitly UNIX time. As such, if you have a time in nanoseconds, you can convert it to a `time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds>`:

```
namespace chrono = std::chrono;

...

using nano_sys = chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock, chrono::nanoseconds>;

auto sys_tp_ns = nano_sys(chrono::nanoseconds(time_in_nanoseconds));
```

Comment: Yes, with clock_gettime I am getting a nanosecond time which is correct (last three digit of the ns field are not zero).

Comment: Okay I'm silly. I was persuaded I was running my code on Linux, but it was running on a different OS with a different stdlib and my question is non-sensical.

Comment: (to be more accurate: it's actually libc++ (llvm) implementation of chrono that uses microseconds, this is surprising!)

Answer (score 5):

> How can I tell std::chrono to use the nanosecond resolution?

This sounds like a good use for writing your own custom clock.  It is much easier than it sounds:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <chrono>

struct my_clock
{
    using duration   = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
    using rep        = duration::rep;
    using period     = duration::period;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<my_clock>;
    static constexpr bool is_steady = false;

    static time_point now()
    {
        timespec ts;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts))
            throw 1;
        using sec = std::chrono::seconds;
        return time_point{sec{ts.tv_sec}+duration{ts.tv_nsec}};
    }
};
```

Just have your `now()` call `clock_gettime` with `CLOCK_REALTIME`.  Then package up the return in a `chrono::time_point` with `nanoseconds` resolution.

Warning, I just tried this on macOS and called `now()` twice in a row.  It printed out the same number of nanoseconds each time.  And there's no way that the call is executing in under a nanosecond.  So I'm getting nanosecond precision, but not nanosecond accuracy.

If you would like `my_clock` to participate in the C++20 `std::chrono::clock_cast` facility (as suggested by Nicol Bolas
in the comments below), add these two static member functions to `my_clock`:

```
template<typename Duration>
static
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>
to_sys(const std::chrono::time_point<my_clock, Duration>& tp)
{
    return std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>
        {tp.time_since_epoch()};
}

template<typename Duration>
static
std::chrono::time_point<my_clock, Duration>
from_sys(const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>& tp)
{
    return std::chrono::time_point<my_clock, Duration>{tp.time_since_epoch()};
}
```

Now you can say things like:

```
cout << clock_cast<system_clock>(my_clock::now()) << '\n';
```

You will also be able to `clock_cast` to or from *all* other C++20 and custom clocks that participate in the `clock_cast` facility.

Comment: You may also want to be able to `clock_cast` it into a nanosecond `system_clock`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be ts.tv_nsec?

Comment: slaps-forehead.  I can't believe it has been wrong for this long!  Thanks for pointing it out.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, mind you that on GCC+libstc++ std::chrono is just a thin wrapper of syntax sugar around clock_gettime().  You are talking about the same thing here. std::chrono uses clock_gettime().

```cpp
    system_clock::time_point
    system_clock::now() noexcept
    {
      timespec tp;
      clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &tp);
      return time_point(duration(chrono::seconds(tp.tv_sec)
                                 + chrono::nanoseconds(tp.tv_nsec)));
    }
```

Source: https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/chrono.cc.html

(above code was cleaned up)

So the precision is there, you just need to retrieve it in nanoseconds with

```
uint64_t utc_now_nanos() {
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point tp = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(tp).time_since_epoch().count();
}
```